# Remove string using sed or awk, grep

Tags: string, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying find and remove strings like:

```
[1126604244001,85.00],  [1122204245002,85.00], [1221104246003,85.00],
[1222204247004,85.00], [1823304248005,85.00], [1424404249006,85.00],
```

85.00 = constans. I mean [xxxxxxxxxxxxx,**85.00**],

In notepad++ is simple:

```
find: "[^........].............,85.00]" and replace:""
```

I wolud like to use awk or sed to remove string automaticly without importing it to notepad++.

ok, I have file

temp.txt

```
[1126604244001,17.00], [1126604244001,17.00], [1126604244001,17.00],
[1126604244001,85.00],  [1122204245002,85.00], [1221104246003,85.00],
    [1222204247004,85.00], [1823304248005,85.00], [1424404249006,85.00], [1126604244001,17.00], [1126604244001,17.00],
```

My desire output

temp.txt

```
[1126604244001,17.00],[1126604244001,17.00],[1126604244001,17.00],[1126604244001,17.00],[1126604244001,17.00],
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] to show your desired output.

Comment: empty the line or delete the line ? you ask remove but show empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, simply:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*,85.00\],[[:space:]]*//g' filename
```

With this, everything that matches the regex `\[[^]]*,85.00\],[[:space:]]*` is removed. The regex matches `[` followed by an arbitrary number of characters that are not `]`, followed by `,85.00],` and optionally spaces; the only syntactically tricky bit is the `[^]]` character set which matches all characters other than `]`.

Alternatively with awk:

```
awk -v RS='],' -v ORS='],' '!/,85.00$/' filename
```

This splits the input into records delimited by `],` and prints only those that don't end with `,85.00`.

Comment: i think `[^,]*` would be better instead of `[^]]*`

Comment: Depends on how OP would want to handle `[1,2,3,85.00]`. With `[^]]*` it would be removed, with `[^,]*` it would stay. For the given input data, both do the same. OP, take your pick.

Comment: I'm going to use:
**sed 's/\[[^]]*,85.00\],*//g' temp.txt >> tempnew.txt**

THX !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -v '[^0-9]85\.00]' YourFile
```

remove (not empty) line with your pattern

Comment: note within a line there can be good and matches and good ones should remain (at least from what I understand from the input / expected output).

Comment: right, post was not clear about remove and clear line/string. It finally seems to remove `[number,85.00]` but not rest of the line. In this case, Wintermute does the good job